# Serving assets in development vs production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, deployment, asset-pipeline

Rails in production mode serves assets from `public/assets` folder like this:

`/assets/application-c3967f04f81628153a30120e3f5b8695.js`

and in development mode serves from `app/assets` folder like this

`/assets/application.js?body=1` or

`/assets/application-c3967f04f81628153a30120e3f5b8695.js`

I wonder how rails figures this out. Because i am trying to do the same in nodejs, i think one approach might be like this:

```
   var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

   if ('development' == env) {
     app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'app')));
   } else if ('production' == env) {
     app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')));
   };
```

What are the alternatives to achieving this in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

**Fingerpriting**

What you're referring to is known as *[asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)*

This is a way for Rails to determine the unique URLs of your assets in production, allowing you to use the likes of [`precompilation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) to serve your assets static, and consequently, quicker

As described in the Rails docs:

> Fingerprinting is a technique that makes the name of a file dependent
>   on the contents of the file. When the file contents change, the
>   filename is also changed. For content that is static or infrequently
>   changed, this provides an easy way to tell whether two versions of a
>   file are identical, even across different servers or deployment dates.

--

**Path Helpers**

The problem you have is when you use Rails in development, it will serve the assets from the `app/assets` directory. However, as you put the app into production, the app will serve assets from the `public` directory instead

This is an issue, as it means you'll have to do some conditional path-loading to get the thing to work. The way around this is to use [asset path helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

These only work with preprocessors like `.erb`, allowing you call the likes of:

```
asset_url("your_asset_url")
```

This will load the asset path independently of whether you're in production or development mode.

---

**NodeJS**

Perhaps you could get a better insight by looking into the [source for `asset_url` path helper](http://rubydoc.info/github/sstephenson/sprockets/Sprockets/Context%3aasset_path) in Rails